# How to optimize a MySQL query which uses variables multiple times?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like the following:

```
SELECT product.id FROM products
INNER JOIN supplier ON supplier.id = product.supplier_id
WHERE supplier.country = 'UK'
AND (
(1000 BETWEEN product.date_on AND product.date_off) OR
(2000 BETWEEN product.date_on AND product.date_off) OR
(2000 >= product.date_on AND 
   (product.date_off IS NULL OR 1000 <= product.date_off))
)
```

That query runs way too slow, and I believe I need some indexes, but I am not sure what to add. I have index on product.date_on and product.date_off, but because I am comparing those values multiple times in the AND clause I believe the indexes aren't used.
Maybe a composite index can be used, but I have no idea which fields and in what order should go in it in order to optimize this.
Btw, 1000 and 2000 are the 2 variables that i am passing...

Comment: Is there anything known about the data? Is date_on always smaller than date_off? Is param1 always smaller than param2?

Answer (score 0):

For optimizing queries, you should look into execution plan.
Just prepend `EXPLAIN` in front of query.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT product.id FROM products ...
```

You can interpret results of `EXPLAIN` using following link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html

Look at parts with maximum `rows` and think how to optimize this parts. Use `possible_keys` as a hint.